Issue with LinkedIn OAuth Integration
I'm encountering an issue while trying to integrate LinkedIn OAuth into my project. When attempting to log in using LinkedIn OAuth, users are presented with the following message:
"Your LinkedIn network will be back soon. We've notified our operations staff that you are having a problem reaching LinkedIn. We'll get you reconnected soon. You can leave this window open and we'll automatically take you back to your LinkedIn home page in a few minutes. We apologize for the interruption."
This issue is critical for our project, and I'm seeking assistance in resolving it as soon as possible.
Steps I've taken so far:
Checked my OAuth credentials and configurations.
Verified that my project's domain is correctly registered with LinkedIn.
Attempted to log in from different devices and networks, but the issue persists.
Snapshot

That sounds like a linkedin bug, which happens all the time. Stack overflow is not the place to get linkedin support.
